# Converting an Excel file into CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: excel, dataframe, powershell, export-to-csv

I tried this code as follows:

```
param(
$inputPath = "N:\Disease_Prevention\....\Samplename.xlsx",
$outputPath = "N:\Disease_Prevention\...\Output.csv"
)

$xlCSV=6
$inputPath = (Resolve-path $inputPath).Path
$outputpath = (Resolve-path $outputpath).Path
get-childitem $inputPath -File | foreach {
    write-host "processing $_ " 
    $Excelfilename = $_.fullname
    if(!$outputPath)
    {
        $outputPath = $_.DirectoryName
    }
    $CSVfilename =join-path $outputpath $_.BaseName
    $CSVfilename+=".csv";
   
    #open excel and save 
    $Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $False
    $Excel.displayalerts=$False
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName)
    $Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV)
    $Excel.Quit()
    If(ps excel){
      kill -name excel
    }
}
```

And received the following error as follows:

[image]

The error says "Unable to get the SaveAs property of the Workbook class"

Would you know why it could be?

And if it's a permission issue, then would you recommend an alternative way to convert excel into csv? Should I use cmdlet to read each line at the excel file and convert one by one?

Answer (score 1):

The issues I encountered with your code are

```
$outputpath = (Resolve-path $outputpath).Path
```

Presumably this CSV file doesn't exist, so when you try to resolve the path it gives you nothing.

```
if(!$outputPath)
{
    $outputPath = $_.DirectoryName
}
$CSVfilename =join-path $outputpath $_.BaseName
$CSVfilename+=".csv";
```

If you don't pass in an outputpath argument, then this will build the file properly. However, if you pass in an outputpath as a csvfile, then you build out a path that looks like

```
"N:\Disease_Prevention\...\Output.csv\inputpath basename.csv"
```

as you're appending the current file's basename and .csv to an already full path.

The adjusted code below worked fine.

```
param(
    $inputPath = "N:\Disease_Prevention\....\Samplename.xlsx",
    $outputPath = "N:\Disease_Prevention\...\Output.csv"
)

$xlCSV=6
$inputPath = (Resolve-path $inputPath).Path

get-childitem $inputPath -File | foreach {
    write-host "processing $_ " 
    $Excelfilename = $_.fullname
    if(!$outputPath)
    {
        $outputPath = $_.DirectoryName
        $CSVfilename = join-path $outputpath $_.BaseName
        $CSVfilename+=".csv"
    }
    else{
        $CSVfilename = $outputPath
    }

    #open excel and save 
    $Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $False
    $Excel.displayalerts=$False
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName)
    $Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV)
    $Excel.Quit()
    If(ps excel){
        kill -name excel
    }

}
```

I also encourage you to check out [Doug Finke](https://twitter.com/dfinke?lang=en)'s [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) powershell module. Makes working with Excel files so much easier and it doesn't require Excel be installed on the machine that runs the script.